# GridLayout rendering differently for different screens

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have been facing this issue for a while and I have no clue as to why this is occuring. On three different screen sizes, the way how the same gridLayout of EditTexts are rendered are completely different.

Here is the XML of a sample EditText in the gridLayout.

```
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/et00"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:background="@drawable/border"
      android:digits="123456789"
      android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"
      android:maxLength="1"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="25sp"
      app:layout_column="0"
      app:layout_columnWeight="0.11"
      app:layout_row="0"
      app:layout_rowWeight="0.11" />
``

border is an XML file in order to mark the boundaries. There are several such kind of XML files for different type of borders (Some cells need to have a darker border on the top for example), but this is the standard border where each boundary is of equal darkening.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <!-- View background color -->
  <solid
      android:color="@color/colorWhite" >
  </solid>

  <stroke
      android:width="0.1dp"
      android:color="@color/colorBlack" >
  </stroke>


</shape>`

The Images attached show how the rendering is different for each phone size 

[Phone 1][1]
[Phone 2][2]
[Phone 3][3] (Worst offender)

Please advice. 


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GW3S.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGaAp.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNnou.png
```

Comment: I have been trying to intend this for a while now my frustration is way too much too handle... Apologies for anyone who tries to help

Comment: You need to use thicker borders at least on small size devices. Using values as small as `0.1dp` is gonna give you a hard time since it may be rounded down to zero pixels in some cases.